Thinkpad charging issues in Ubuntu 24.04
Thinkpad x1 extreme gen 2
Intel Core i7, 32gb, 1tb
BIOS version 1.5 (current)
Ubuntu 24.04 bare metal
kernels tried: 6.8.0-31-generic (most stable, current), 6.8.8 (unstable, reverted back)
Brand new battery as of May 6, 2024
135w charger
TLP installed, active, default settings
Secure boot off in BIOS
USB always on in BIOS
Wayland
Charging is intermittent, has a mind of its own. Laptop will power swap when opening apps, closing apps, opening/closing the laptop case. Charging will start/stop at random levels, no charging thresholds set in TLP. Sometimes  it starts/stops only once and for a second, sometimes repeatedly until I disconnect the charger and reconnect. This behavior follows with different chargers, different wall outlets, two different internal batteries, power management enabled and disabled in BIOS. TLP installed or uninstalled no change.
Suspend throws the laptop into an unusable state. I have to force shutdown holding the power button and reboot to use laptop. When waking from suspend, a charged battery will sometimes read critically low, and shut down the laptop, sometimes I will have enough time to login, log out, log back in and the battery will read its actual level. Therefore suspend mode is completely disabled. I have reinstalled Ubuntu 24.04 from USB, no change. Battery life is normal - just erratic charging behavior.
User 'Hennsensen' reports similar issues at this link:
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2024/04/ubuntu-24-04-battery-life-improvements#comment-6454078615 leading me to believe it is not a hardware issue.
Please let me know what command outputs would be useful in troubleshooting.

Charging is 100% only hardware related. the OS gets info from bios about state and statistics. It is likely your connector as that part is fragile.

I am having this exact same issue with my Lenovo P1 gen2 using any 6.8.0 kernel or newer.
I found this open bug over on launchpad which seems to match exactly: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2067043.
If that bug report also matches for you, could you please also confirm that it affects you so that it is voted higher, increasing our chances that it will be looked at. :)
My workaround until this is fixed is to run either the 23.10 Ubuntu kernel (6.5.0) or mainline 6.7.10.
